# Why is Html.BeginForm() action= stripped?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to use BeginForm() but it isn't working.

When I try:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "HomeContoller", FormMethod.Post)
```

The rendered form tag `action=` doesn't have a value.

I have to revert back to using a regular form tag, which works:

```
<form action="MyAction" method="post">
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: since home controller is the default, my guess it is being removed since it is assumed.  If you post the form with your first using, does it work?

Comment: What do you mean by "post the form with your first using"?

Comment: Can you post your RouteConfig RegisterRoutes() method?

Comment: click a submit button and see if it still posts back to where you are wanting it to go

Comment: clicking the submit button doesn't do anything.

Comment: @br4d.net: This is an asp.net 5 Website app.  I don't see a RouteConfig or RegisterRoutes().

Comment: MVC5 should have a RouteConfig.cs located in the App_Start folder. It has a method called RegisterRoutes() which is bootstrapped on app start from the Global.asax. This file determines how the routing works and how the URLs are generated from these HTML helpers.

Comment: There is no such folder.